# How to sort elements of a vector due to another data?

Tags: r

I have a vector which is like `c(x, y, z)`, and lists like;

```
x <- list("a"= 2, "b"= 3)
y <- list("a"= 1, "c"= 4)
z <- list("a"= 3, "d"= 5)
```

which has the same names with elements of the initial vector.
I want to sort the vector due to scores of "a" within lists.

The expected result is `c(y, x, z)`.
Every help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `base R` approach,

```
x <- list("a"= 2, "b"= 3)
y <- list("a"= 1, "c"= 4)
z <- list("a"= 3, "d"= 5)

v  <- c("x", "y", "z")

names(sort(sapply(v, function(i){get(i)[["a"]]})))
```

gives,

```
"y" "x" "z"
```

Comment: `v[order(sapply(mget(v), "[[", "a"))]`

Comment: This is the most useful approach for me, thank you, it really works. How can I make this work when there is another element in the vector v, yet not a list with same name?

Comment: @Elif If it is the only one which hasn’t got the same name with the list, it can be handled by ‘%in%’ operator. Otherwise -if you have more than one-, you need to define which element of  the vector is reperesented by the one of the lists.

Comment: I've solved this problem by doing this: 
`newv <- as.vector(names(which(lapply(sapply(v, function(i){get(i)[["a"]]}), is.null) == F)))
c(names(sort(sapply(newv, function(i){get(i)[["a"]]}))), as.vector(names(which(lapply(sapply(v, function(i){get(i)[["a"]]}), is.null) == T))))`

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
f <- list(x, y, z)
f[order(unlist(sapply(f, "[", "a")))]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it does not give the expected result.

Comment: actually it is the only answer that gives the expected result as it was asked for `c(y, x ,z)` and not `c("y", "x","z")` ;)

Answer (score 0):

An option with `map`

```
library(tidyverse)
list(x, y, z) %>%
    map_dbl(pluck, "a") %>%
    order %>% 
   c('x', 'y', 'z')[.]
#[1] "y" "x" "z"
```